# Expression for a logarithm of the Weierstrass sigma functions

Tags: weierstrass-preparation

Lets consider a following function
\begin{equation}
f(z) = \ln{\frac{\sigma (z - v)}{\sigma (z + v)}}, 
\end{equation}
where $\sigma$ is Weierstrass sigma function, and $v$ is a constant. Is there a way to express these formula as a function of Weierstrass $\wp$ and $\wp'$ functions istead of $\sigma$?

I'm mainly interested in whether we can get $v$ out of the $\sigma$ function, $z$ can stay in it.

Comment: This function is neither analytic nor even  meromorphic (has logarithic singularities). Why do you expect it is expressible in terms of $\wp$ and $\wp'$?

Comment: The main reason is that it would help me to solve a different problem I'm working on. I agree with your arguments, but I am new to elliptical functions and wondered if there are any methods I am unfamiliar with that allow me to transform this expression.